# translate3d inside overflow:hidden leaks to second page when printed

Tags: css, printing, overflow, mapbox, translate3d

I'm working on generating report that contains a map. I use Mapbox for this purpose. I came across an issue with one of the tiles leaking out to the second page in print preview (tested in Chrome). I've spent most part of the day trying to tackle the issue. I seem to have figured out the root cause. Map tiles are placed on the element that is positioned using `transform: translate3d`. I've put together a simple example that demonstrates the issue.

```css
html {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tile {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  transform: translate3d(-100px, 300px, 0px);
  background-color: green;
}

.another-block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
<div class="another-block"></div>
```

If you load it in Chrome (or PhantomJS) and open Print Preview (in Chrome of course) you will notice that green rectangle leaks into the second page.
However, if you change negative left offset (-100px) to positive, the problem goes away.

Any idea on how to fix this? There is an option to fetch the exact map region as an image which will require rebuilding a big part of the system as opposed to using Mapbox out of the box. So before going there I'd like to ask if anybody has solved similar issues before.

**UPDATE:**

`@page {margin: 0}` (suggested in the answer) didn't help. Here're the screenshots:

- Without margin: 0
  [image: Without margin: 0]
- With margin: 0
  [image: With margin: 0]

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `@page { margin: 0 }`

Before:
[image: Without @page]

After:
[image: With @page]

However, for finer control, you could play with `@media: print` to get those reports nice and polished :)

Good luck!

## Edit:

As you mentioned, the layout is Landscape. Portrait does "bleed" over the pages, like:

[image: Portrait Bleeding]

However, you can control the elements and when they break by using CSS like `page-break-before` or `page-break-after`. You then get something like this:

#### Portrait

[image]

#### Landscape

[image]

These have `page-break-after` applied to `.another-block`, with `@page { margin: 0}`

Comment: On your screenshot the page has landscape orientation. If you turn it to portrait you'll see that margin: 0 doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Having that said I just realize that it doesn't make sense. In landscape orientation you have event less vertical space than in portrait. Anyway, I tried adding margin: 0 to @page and it didn't help in my case. The weird thing is that you made blue-bordered div to exactly fit the first page.

Comment: You're right about the portrait orientation @Iurr-r. You could play with `page-break-before` (or maybe `page-break-after` for the containing element) to allow elements to not cross over pages. I'll edit my comment to demonstrate.

Comment: I'm still unable to hide that leaking part even after playing with page-break-before/after. Could you please share your complete code example? I can see in you screenshot that you don't experience this problem. However, it still persists for me.